# How to sync only mapped subfoldrs in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, tfs, visual-studio-2015

Lets say I have this folder structure in my local computer. Here, root folder not mapped.

```
_unmapped-root
|__mapped-1
|__unmapped-1
|__unmapped-2
|__mapped-2
|__mapped-3
```

So in TFS, is there a way to sync these three mapped folders (mapped_1, mapped_2, mapped_3) without specifying their names separately.

something like

`tfs get $mybase/unmapped-root/*`  What only sync what ever the mapped sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively map portions of your repository into a workspace.  In this case, map just the 3 mapped folders and none of the others, like this:

[image: Workspace mapping]

Bonus: the last line maps the root folder contents non-recursively, so you'll get files in the root, but you won't get any folders that aren't explicitly mapped to the workspace otherwise (i.e. unmapped folders).

Now you can just execute `tf get` to fetch the latest contents of your full workspace according to your mapping.

Extra bonus: if you want to unmap something (e.g. $/root/Mapped1/UnmappedSubfolder), add it to your workspace mapping and change the status from Active to Cloaked.